# make an HttpsURLConnection request with parameters by method post

Tags: java, javafx, httpsurlconnection

**process an https page sending its parameters**

**Java8u201 using HttpsURLConnection**

```
String httpsURL = "https://www.wmtechnology.org/Consultar-RUC/";
URL myUrl = null;

String[][] parameter = { { "modo", "1" }, { "btnBuscar", "Buscar" }, { "nruc", "10460332759" } };
System.out.println(parameter.toString());

try {
    myUrl = new URL(httpsURL);
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();


    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(parameter.toString());
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    }
    br.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**returns the page but without data**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong on the line

```
wr.writeBytes(parameter.toString());
```

because `parameter.toString()` returns string like `[[Ljava.lang.String;@1f554b06` instead of expected `param1=value1&param2=value2 etc.`

So correct this part to

```
    String parameterString = Arrays.stream(parameter)
            .map(pair -> pair[0] + "=" + pair[1])
            .collect(Collectors.joining("&"));
    wr.writeBytes(parameter.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a library which handles the underlying connection/request for you. The Apache HTTP Client has a fluent API which would make the code easier to write:

```
        String result = Request
                .Post("https://www.wmtechnology.org/Consultar-RUC/")
                .bodyForm(Form
                        .form()
                        .add("modo", "1")
                        .add("btnBuscar", "Buscar")
                        .add("nruc", "10460332759")
                        .build())
                .execute()
                .returnContent()
                .asString();
        System.out.println(result);
```

More information here: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.2.x/tutorial/html/fluent.html

This request does return data.

Comment: it also works with Apache HttpClient Fluent API, thanks